# Magento Tax calculations wrong - inc vat and ex vat are the same… Paypal adding tax and delivery twice…

Tags: magento, paypal

I’m having issues with the tax calculations on my site.

The prices are set to be including tax. I have a group price set for trade customers (also including tax). Everything works fine if I am not logged in and go through the checkout as a guest user.

But when I log in as a trade customer and go to the cart, the Excl tax and Inc tax are the same value (see: http://phyto5.co.uk/Checkout.png)

Then when i go through to PayPal, the tax and delivery get added onto the grand total again (see http://phyto5.co.uk/PayPal.png)

Any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE:

Looking into this further it looks like the wrong values are being passed to paypal, so it's definitely a magento issue not a paypal one.

If I add a product costing £20, which includes £3.33 tax, and has an additional £4.95 shipping. The payment_paypal_standard log file shows the following is being passed through:

[amount] => 24.95

[tax] => 3.33

[shipping] => 4.95

Paypal then adds the three together to give the total amount payable.

Thanks
Steve

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue before 1 month and I've over come this issue by doing some below stuff and it worked.

Please follow the instruction.

```
<magento root dir>app\code\core\Mage\Sales\etc
```

and open `config` xml and add **msrp** according to screenshot

```
http://prntscr.com/fxhcu0
```

Now go to system `configuration` and open Tax tab and make your `settings`.

Editing core file is not good idea, but for testing just do it and then you can override that config node to your custom module's xml.

Hope it helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to disable the "Transfer Cart Line Items" option for the PayPal payment method you are using. By disabling this, Magento will no longer give details about the totals, tax and shipping to PayPal. It will simply tell PayPal to charge the customer for a single item (for which you can specify your own text under "Summary Text for Aggregated Cart") with a value of the total order amount.

The bug seems to be in Magento though and not in PayPal. I think it only occurs when your shipping fees do not include sales tax and Magento has to add the sales tax in the grand total.

just try in this way,

let me know if i can help you further

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, but that doesn't seem to make any difference. I've updated the above question with more details.